# usage of MATCH in Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question on how MATCH is used.

This initially all started when I want to find out "How many distinct/unique items are in my range of values". After a bit of research, this formula apparently does the job quite well:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0),MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0))>0,1))
```

Which "Counts the number of unique text and number values in cells B2:B10 (which must not contain blank cells)"

I want to understand this formula a bit better, so I copied out this part and paste it somewhere else:

```
MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0)
```

And this evaluates to "#Value!".

In this case, how is excel getting the job done in the first place? Searching up how MATCH works didn't tell me much, as the examples require a "value" and not a "range" to be put in the first argument...

Any insights into this would be much appreciated!

FYI - for those interested in got the first formula here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273?CorrelationId=4331e8f6-e4d5-4210-9b21-3ed53ee45a6d&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Instead of copying part of formula to another cell you can use `Evaluate formula` option to watch step by step execution. Here's an example article about it: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/formula-auditing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True - but the vast majority of functions can operate over, not just one, but also a range of values.

In almost all cases this involves committing the formula as an *array formula* (i.e. with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER), though some functions, including FREQUENCY, have the innate ability to coerce an array of returns without this keystroke combination.

And that explains your #VALUE! error: the MATCH construction will not, *on its own*, evaluate over all elements in the array being passed to it: it requires some external function to both coerce, and process the results of, an array of returns, which is here achieved by the FREQUENCY function.

Actually that construction is not the most efficient: the repetition of the MATCH clause for the *bins_array* is not necessary, and means that the construction is unduly resource-heavy. Neither is the comparator (>0) strictly necessary. Better is simply:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0),ROW(B2:B10)-MIN(ROW(B2:B10))+1),1))`

since - and especially over larger ranges - despite the additional function calls, the construction:

`ROW(B2:B10)-MIN(ROW(B2:B10))+1`

is likely to be far quicker to calculate than one which involves linear searching.

Regards

P.S. If in addition you want an explanation as to how this construction works, just let me know.

Comment: Not only did you answer my question, you provided another solution for me use on my spreadsheet. Thanks!!