# MATCH() function in Excel and PowerPivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I know I can use the MATCH() function in Excel to find the relative position of an item. However, I have 2 problems:
1) Suppose I'm looking for the relative position of an element which appears more than once in my range, how can I get **all** the relative positions of the element?
2) Suppose I'm doing the same thing on PowerPivot, is there any equivalent of the MATCH() function to do the same job?

To clarify my question with an example, suppose I have the following data:

[image]

I'm interested in finding all the row numbers where appear the number 1, both in Excel and PowerPivot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [usage of MATCH in Excel formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682362/usage-of-match-in-excel-formula)

Comment: To what end, how is this data to be used?  There may be a better way if we know the bigger picture.  Otherwise I believe that vba may be the way to go.

Comment: @Scott Craner:  I have a time series of stock prices. Suppose I get 1 when the stock price crosses a given threshold, and 0 otherwise. I want to check at which date (i.e. which cell) the theshold has been crossed.

Comment: Alright now we can use the `SMALL()` Function.  Say your date/time is in column B.  In C1 put `=SMALL(IF(A:A = 1,B:B),row(1:1))`.  Press Ctrl-Shift-Enter, because it is an array formula.  Then copy down.  This will put in order from earliest to latest every time that column A:A is one.